# SCSS compiler not working with variable for @media

Tags: sass

I'm trying to figure out why this fails

```
$media-xsmall: screen and (max-width: 600px);
// OR, $media-xsmall: (screen and (max-width: 600px));
@media #{$media-xsmall}{
  // something
}
```

But this runs without problems

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
  // something
  .test{
    color: green;
  }
}
```

The error that I'm getting is:

```
Error: (max-width: 600px) isn't a valid CSS value.
        on line 2 of stdin
>> $media-xsmall: screen and (max-width: 600px);
   ---------------------------^
```

Anybody got any tips/advice on why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't store a value like this in a variable, you need to put it between quotation marks:

```
$media-xsmall: "screen and (max-width: 600px)";

@media #{$media-xsmall} {
  .test{
    color: green;
  }
}
```